# Trouble with video.currentTime event binding

Tags: javascript, html, events, video

I want to fire an event after the video has reached 5 or more seconds, but I'm having some trouble with the code.

HTML:

```
<video id="video1" controls>
    <source src="media/video.m4v" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="media/video.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <source src="media/video.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
    <p> Your browser does not support the HTML5 video feature. </p>
</video>
```

Javascript:

```
 $(function () {

    var video = $('#video1');
    var time = 5;
    function init () {
        alert('Video is not available.');
    }

    $(video).on('timeupdate', function () {
        if (video.currentTime >= time) {
            init();
        }
    });

 });
```

This is unfortunately not a valid code, does anybody know where I went wrong...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get `undefined` because video is jQuery object that does not have property `currentTime`, you can get this value like this

```
video.get(0).currentTime
```

or

```
this.currentTime
```

Example

```
 $(function () {

    var video = $('#video1');
    var time = 5;
    function init () {
        alert('Video is not available.');
    }

    video.on('timeupdate', function () {
        if (video.get(0).currentTime >= time) {
            init();
        }
    });

 });
```